# Reference to a pointer of an object's super-type doesn't compile in a lambda function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lambda

```
auto func = [](IUnknown *&pIThis) { ... }

ISomething *pSomething = ...;
func(pSomething);
```

This does not compile (in MSVC 2013) but removing the '`&`' means it does. Is this a basic C++ issue I've misunderstood, or specific to a lambda, or even a VC++ issue?

And what is the solution - pointer-to-a-pointer, or something else?

> error C2664: 'void (__vectorcall *)(IUnknown *&)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'ISomething *' to 'IUnknown *&'

Comment: This can't possibly work - not without a cast. If it worked, `func` could make `pSomething` point to `ISomethingElseEntirely` (also derived from `IUnknown`), which would be a type safety violation. This is basic C++, unrelated to lambdas. If you think you know what you are doing, then write `func(reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*&>(pSomething))`

Comment: Doh! So obvious now you point that out. I think that's a fairly complete answer to be honest.